# can't find data in django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have some questions about django orm with mysql.

This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

#电影列表
class Movieinfo(models.Model):
    movienum = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    moviename = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    movierelease_time = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    movietype = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["movienum"]
    def __str__(self):
        return self.moviename

#短评论
class Moviescritic(models.Model):
    movieinfo = models.ForeignKey(Movieinfo)
    movienum = models.IntegerField()
    moviescrit= models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["movienum"]
    def __str__(self):
        return self.moviescrit

#长影评
class Movielcritic(models.Model):
     movieinfo = models.ForeignKey(Movieinfo)
     movienum = models.IntegerField()
     movielcrittitle = models.TextField()
     movielcrit = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["movienum"]
    def __str__(self):
        return self.movielcrit
```

This is my views.py

```
import logging

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from django.template import loader

from yingping.models import Moviescritic

logger = logging.getLogger('__name__')

def cdview(request):
    template = loader.get_template('worldcloud.html')

    movie_shu = Moviescritic.objects.filter(
        movieinfo__movienum='10014'
    )
    content = {
        'movie_shu':movie_shu,
    }

   return HttpResponse(template.render(content,request))
```

But I can't find any data in html, is my understanding of django `onetomany` wrong?

```
{% block worldcloud %}
    {% if movie_shu %}
        {% for x in movie_shu %}
            <p>{{x}}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        print("err")
    {% endif %}
        <!--SERVICES SECTION END  -->
{% endblock %}
```

the html just find `print("error")`, when i find data in itself table I can find data in HTML. so what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you tried to `print movie_shu` in your view before returning?

Comment: what `Moviescritic.objects.filter(movieinfo__movienum='10014').exists()` returns?

Comment: when i use movie_shu =Moviescritic.objects.filter(movieinfo__movienum='10014').exists() and print(movie_shu),it's False. i think my problem in foreignkey ,because  i  copy other's data to these table (but other's data doesn't have foreignkey)  and i  add foreignkey  using mysql not django.